# Journey Builder : Event based entry source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

Are event based entry sources in place of an automation studio audience or data filter?

I've created a Date based event and used available attributes from my main tables and set contact filters to what I require. Will this suffice as a sendable list and will this place customers into the journey or am I missing another step, seem's too easy that's why I have the questions. Also it uses data from multiple tables but there are no queries etc?

Comment: Which data extension is the entry event looking at? As long as it's a sendable DE this should pull in anyone (subject to entry criteria) that you need. Personally I like to filter people into a data extension built purely for that journey, and joined in an attribute set & population. I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence however.